# Find out if any files inside folder, sub-folder were modified in last 24 hours through windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to know if there is a way by which I can find out if any files inside folder, sub-folder were modified in last 24 hours through windows CMD.

I tried to use 'Forfiles' cmd command but it seems it doesn't take 'time' parameter.

forfiles /P directory /S /C "cmd /c echo @path" /D +9/12/2017

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As the batch file is most likely executed once per day, it would be most likely the best to process each file having archive attribute set and then remove the archive attribute. So the batch file could detect every day which files were modified or copied into the directory in the last 24 hours independent on their file dates. Example: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "Directory" /AA-D /B /S 2^>nul') do echo Modified or added: "%%I" & %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -a "%%I"`

Comment: @Mofi - thanks for your response. My folder structure is something like this.. Parent Folder has 2 child folders.. 'Folder_1', 'Folder_2'... 'Folder_1' contains sub-folders which contain XML and .resx files.. 'Folder_2' contains 1 XML file.. How do I edit your above command to suffice my requirement? Still trying to understand how above command works.. Also, is there any harm in using System32\attrib.exe in a script?

My Goal is to find out if there is addition/modification/deletion in any file present inside parent folder. And if yes then need to commit those changes in GIT.

Comment: @Mofi - what is the purpose of 2^ in the above command?

Comment: The error message output by __DIR__ in case of no file with archive attribute in directory tree is suppressed by redirecting it to device __NUL__. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter parses the __FOR__ command line. Later on execution of __DIR__ command line in a separate command process in background `>` is interpreted as redirection operator. Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).